# How do I use distinct for a column along with a where clause in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, distinct, where-clause

I want to get the distinct value of a particular column however duplicity is not properly managed if more than 3 columns are selected.

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ShoppingSessionId, userid 
FROM 
  dbo.tbl_ShoppingCart 
GROUP BY 
  ShoppingSessionId, userid 
HAVING
  userid = 7
```

This query produces correct result, but if we add another column then result is wrong.

Please help me as I want to use the `ShoppingSessionId` as a distinct, except when I want to use all the columns from the table, including with the `where` clause .

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please post sample data from ShoppingCart and desired results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` keyword applies to the entire row, never to a column.

Presently `DISTINCT` is not needed at all, because your script already makes sure that `ShoppingSession` is distinct: by specifying the column in `GROUP BY` and filtering on the other grouping column (`userid`).

When you add a third column to `GROUP BY` and it results in duplicated `ShoppingSession`, it means that some `ShoppingSession` values are associated with many different values of the added column.

If you want `ShoppingSession` to remain distinct after including that third column, you should decide which values of the the added column should be left in the output and which should be discarded. This is called *aggregating*. You could apply the `MAX()` function to that column, or `MIN()` or any other suitable [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx). Note that the column should *not* be included in `GROUP BY` in this case.

Here's an illustration of what I'm talking about:

```
SELECT
  ShoppingSessionId,
  userid,
  MAX(YourThirdColumn) AS YourThirdColumn
FROM dbo.tbl_ShoppingCart
GROUP BY
  ShoppingSessionId,
  userid
HAVING userid = 7
```

There's one more note on your query. The `HAVING` clause is typically used for filtering on aggregated columns. If your filter does not involve aggregated columns, you'll be better off using the `WHERE` clause instead:

```
SELECT
  ShoppingSessionId,
  userid,
  MAX(YourThirdColumn) AS YourThirdColumn
FROM dbo.tbl_ShoppingCart
WHERE userid = 7
GROUP BY
  ShoppingSessionId,
  userid
```

Although both queries would produce identical results, their efficiency would be different, because the first query would have to pull all rows, group/aggregate them, then discard all rows except `userid = 7`, but the second one would discard rows first and only then group/aggregate the remaining, which is much more efficient.

You could go even further and exclude the `userid` column from `GROUP BY` and pull its value with an aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  ShoppingSessionId,
  MAX(userid) AS userid,
  MAX(YourThirdColumn) AS YourThirdColumn
FROM dbo.tbl_ShoppingCart
WHERE userid = 7
GROUP BY
  ShoppingSessionId
```

Since all `userid` values in your output are supposed to contain `7` (because that's in your filter), you can just pick a maximum value per every `ShoppingSession`, knowing that it'll always be `7`.